# npm install solc and solc-cli but failed in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, ethereum

when i try to use npm  to install solc and solc-cli

```
    npm WARN deprecated lodash.assign@4.2.0: This package is deprecated. Use Object.assign.
/usr/local/bin/solcjs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc/solcjs
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package solc does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer solc-cli@0.3.0 wants solc@^0.3.5

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "solc"
npm ERR! cwd /home/hzxscyq
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hzxscyq/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

and i want to know how to solve it.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update your Node and NPM versions! Later versions don't use peerDependencies anymore.

Version `4.6` (LTS) or `6.7` are the latest ones you can get of Node. And `3.10.8` is the current version of NPM.

Once you updated both everything should run perfectly fine!